# Understanding the return this in timer.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was just going through [the code of timer.js](https://github.com/jchavannes/jquery-timer/blob/master/jquery.timer.js#L108), playing around with the dev tools in Chrome, and basically I call the plugin like so:

```
var timer = $.timer(function(){
                $('#add-html').html('Hello There !!');    
            });


            timer.set({ time:5000 , autostart :true });
```

Even the demo uses the same example, now when the below line executed:

```
  var timer = $.timer(function(){
                    $('#add-html').html('Hello There !!');    
                });
```

[This line](https://github.com/jchavannes/jquery-timer/blob/master/jquery.timer.js#L108) inside the plugin executes and `returns this`, but what is `return this` at this point? Is it an instance of the whole plugin? Or what is it exactly, I know without it an error is thrown, but what exactly is `return this` used here for and what is its `value`?

I use `return this` a lot for chaining etc in JavaScript, but somehow I am not able to understand the contextual usage of the `return this` here. Would anybody explain ?

Comment: return this retuns the $.timer instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just run this in a debugger (set either a breakpoint or a `debugger` statement) and evaluate `this` at that point.

For me, `this === jQuery` is true on the first run and `this instanceof $.timer` is true on subsequent runs.

Comment: hmm... so the plugin is attaching properties to `jQuery` on first run. that seems a little dangerous, for example, it would be overriding the `toggle` method with its own...

Comment: Yes, I didn't write the plugin but usually I see the use of `$.fn.pluginName = function(...)` which creates the plugin on `$.prototype` instead of as a direct property.

Comment: $.fn wouldn't make sense here, as that would mean it's attached to an element (which isn't needed here.) It just needs to be separated. Just confirming your findings.

Comment: Ah, it's not overwriting methods on $.fn, it's overwriting methods on $ directly. so toggle isn't an issue, it's just not a good idea. I doubt the author realizes what it is doing, i'll submit an issue.